# Window manager with python support/extensions

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, desktop-environment, tiling-wm

My preferred desktop environment lately has been Lxde. I like handling most things from the command line, so Gnome and KDE always seem to get in my way more than I like. But I do envy some of the new window manager features. Openbox does a pretty good job (and with lxde it does slightly better).

But, I would really like to have dynamic keybindings at times and smarter window tiling/auto-arrangement. Static configs just don't quite cut it sometimes. It seems like some python hooks would do the trick, but I haven't had much luck finding support for it.

I was hoping someone knows of a python project that ties into openbox or some other compliant window manager. I've seen some newer WMs (qtile for instance) but I am a bit weary of its age/reliability.

I really don't need widget support and all that jazz, just looking for scriptable keybindings, and a semi-pleasant wrapper around window control. Do you know of any such projects? or am I looking at python/xlib solution?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

Depending on how much effort you want to put into it, looking at [PLWM](http://plwm.sourceforge.net/) or [Qtile](http://www.qtile.org/) might be worthwhile. Then there is also [PyWM](http://pywm.sourceforge.net/), which seems to be "stable" at this moment.

Last but not least, looking around on the internet doesn't seem to be that hopeless: for example [this blog](http://sqizit.bartletts.id.au/2011/03/28/how-to-write-a-window-manager-in-python/) looks as possibly useful.

If you are not insisting on Python, there are some WMs that are extensible in [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)).

Comment: I am trying not to completely replace the traditional WM, if possible (any blackbox derivative would be great). I noticed some of the pure python WMs, but that is why my title mentioned extensions (as opposed to complete rewrites). PLWM is at least in the Deb7 repositories, so I will take a closer look at it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what I wanted, [PyWO](https://code.google.com/p/pywo/).

Only depends on python-xlib and claims to work with any EWMH compatible manager (openbox included!). Have not tested yet, but these are the features I wanted (drop in extension as opposed to a clobber everything replacement).

Pure py WMs seem cool, but I dont want to manage everything, only those few windowing features that make development life a little less painless.